# Python argsparse to filter for a region

Tags: command-line-interface, argparse

```
  parser.add_argument('-r', '--regions', nargs="*", choices=["us-east-1", "us-west-2"], default=["us-east-1"],
                        type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.action == 'list':
        list_response = secrets_session.list_secrets()
        print(json.dumps(list_response, indent=4, default=str))
```

ask- in the above code,i have to list only for the specific region input by the user in cli.how can send the choices from args parser?
cmd i am trying is not filtering the region- python -m file -a list -r 'us-east-1'

i have added the list with the choices and tried to input in the cmdline,but looks like i need to add a if condition or soemwhere to pick the specific choices.

Comment: Add a `print(args)` so you have a clearer idea of what the parser has found.  It that's the only `add_argument`, I wouldn't expect to see a `args.action`, rather just a `args.regions`.

Comment: thank you .i was able to debug the issue after adding print(args) and had to to define the args.region which was the issue.